# Having Issue with error refreshing access token

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Hi I am trying to connect to Big Query and I am using a google service account with a JSON key.  I am getting the below error. This is in my java batch program.

Insert operation not performed
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Unexpected error refreshing access token

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue. more here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization

```
import com.google.auth.Credentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Dataset;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.URI;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String projectId = "myproject";
        // Load JSON file that contains service account keys and create ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials object.
        String credentialsPath = "/path/to/key.json";
        URI audience = URI.create("https://bigquery.googleapis.com/");
        Credentials credentials = null;
        try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
            credentials = ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.fromStream(is, audience);
        }
        // Instantiate BigQuery client with the credentials object.
        BigQuery bigquery =
                BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
        // Use the client to list BigQuery datasets.
        System.out.println("Datasets:");
        bigquery
            .listDatasets(projectId)
            .iterateAll()
            .forEach(dataset -> System.out.printf("%s%n", dataset.getDatasetId().getDataset()));
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the key.json look like? what are its contents?